# Brackets recursive code folding

Tags: javascript, adobe-brackets

Is there an extension for brackets that would allow me to collapse all functions in the document simultaneously? And by that I mean any time I open up a function all of its collapsible children are collapsed, as are their children. Currently I just alt-click the collapse button and then pop it back open, but this only collapses the first level of children. I want to collapse everything at once.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `brackets-code-folding` by `thehogfather` on github.

Link : https://github.com/thehogfather/brackets-code-folding

Comment: I've used this with the same issue

Comment: @user3649110, I have read its documentation. it says that it can resolve your issue. to be honest I haven't used the extension. but I encourage you to read its documentation.